# How can I filter these search results in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, search, extjs, filter

I have a search.js file (part of a large script) that handles searching through files & folders and returning the results.

I am trying to filter the search results so that any file names or paths that contain *"unwanted"* are not displayed.

This is the search.js file in it's entirety:

```
FR = {
    UI: {translations:[]}
};

function setLookInValue() {
    var path = window.parent.FR.searching.path.replace('/ROOT/HOME', '');
    lookin.setValue(path ? path : '/');
    FR.grid.getStore().removeAll();
}

Ext.onReady(function() {
    window.parent.Ext.get(window.parent.FR.UI.searchPopup.getLayout().container.body.dom).unmask();
metadataField = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: FR.T('Metadata Field'),
    autoCreate:true, mode: 'local',
    emptyText:FR.T('Select...'),
    displayField:'filetype',
    valueField:'id', name: 'metadata_field_id', hiddenName:'metadata_field_id',
    editable: false, triggerAction:'all', disableKeyFilter: true,
    forceSelection:true, value:0, width:130,
    store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['id', 'filetype'],
        data: FR.metadataFields
    })
});
metadataValue = new Ext.form.TextField({
    fieldLabel: FR.T('Metadata'), name: 'metadata_value', width: 130, value: ''
});
FR.rightColumnFields = [];
if (window.parent.User.perms.metadata) {
    FR.rightColumnFields.push(metadataField);
    FR.rightColumnFields.push(metadataValue);
}
FR.rightColumnFields.push(new Ext.Button({
    text: FR.T('Search'),
    style: (!window.parent.User.perms.metadata ? '' : 'margin-left:98px'),
    handler: function(){
         ds.load({
            params:{
                filename: Ext.getCmp('filename').getValue(),
                keyword: Ext.getCmp('keyword').getValue(),
                metafield: metadataField.getValue(),
                metavalue: metadataValue.getValue(),
                path: encodeURIComponent(window.parent.FR.searching.path)
            }
        });
    }
}));

FR.form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    labelAlign: 'right',
    labelWidth: 90,
    border: false,
    hideBorders: true,
    bodyBorder: false,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px',
    items: [{
        layout:'column',
        items: [{
            columnWidth:.5,
            layout: 'form',
            border: false, bodyBorder: false,
            items: [{
                id: 'filename', xtype:'textfield',
                fieldLabel: FR.T('File name'),
                name: 'file_name', width: 130, value: ''
            },
            {
                id: 'keyword', xtype:'textfield',
                fieldLabel: FR.T('File contents'),
                name: 'file_contents',
                width: 130, value: '',
                disabled: !window.parent.Settings.fullTextSearch
            },
            lookin = new Ext.form.TextField({
                fieldLabel: FR.T('Look in'),
                name: 'lookin', width: 130, value: '', readOnly: true
            })
            ]
        },{
            columnWidth:.5,
            id: 'secondCol',
            layout: 'form',
            border: false,
            bodyBorder: false,
            items: FR.rightColumnFields
        }]
    }]
});

var ds = new Ext.data.Store({
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: URLRoot+'/?module=search&section=ajax&page=search'
    }),
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            root: 'files',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount',
            id: 'id'
        }, 
        [
            {name: 'icon'},
            {name: 'id'},
            {name: 'filename'},
            {name: 'path'},
            {name: 'technical_path'},
            {name: 'score', type: 'float'}
        ]
    )
});

var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    defaults: {sortable: true},
    columns: [
        {id: 'filename', header: FR.T("File name"), dataIndex: 'filename', width: 160,
            renderer: function (value, p, record) {
                return '<img src="'+URLRoot+'/images/fileman/file_icons/small/'+record.data.icon+'" width="16" height="16" align="absmiddle"> '+value;
            }
        },
        {id: 'path', header: FR.T("Path"), dataIndex: 'path'}
    ]
});
cm.defaultSortable = true;

grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    ds: ds,
    cm: cm,
    border: false, bodyBorder: false, hideBorders: true,
    selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
    loadMask: {msg: FR.T('Searching...')},
    enableColumnHide: false,
    enableColumnMove: false,
    autoExpandColumn: 'path',
    selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:true})
});

grid.on('rowclick', function (grid, rowIndex, e){
    var rowData = grid.getStore().data.items[rowIndex].data;
    var path = rowData.technical_path;
    var filename = rowData.filename;
    if (window.parent.FR.currentPath != path) {
        window.parent.FR.UI.tree.panel.selectPath(path, 'pathname', function() {
            window.parent.FR.UI.grid.highlightOnDisplay = filename;
        });
    } else {
        window.parent.FR.UI.grid.highlight(filename);
    }
});

grid.on('rowcontextmenu', function(grid, rowIndex, e) {e.stopEvent();return false;})
FR.grid = grid;

new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'border',
    hideBorders: true,
    items: [
        {
            region: 'north', layout: 'fit', split: true, height:100,
            hideBorders: true, bodyBorder: false, border: false,
            items: [FR.form]
        },
        {
            region: 'center', layout: 'fit', autoHeigh: true,
            items: grid
        }
    ]
});
setLookInValue();
});
```

I'm pretty lost. I thought somewhere in the code I could do something like:

```
if (someVar.indexOf("unwanted") == -1) { ...
```

Is there anything in this JavaScript that would give anyone enough info to help me filter these search results?

Comment: That is quite a lot of code. Please try to cut it down to the most important parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like code that uses Ext JS, and I have added a tag accordingly.  A little sniffing through the documentation suggests that the Filtering and Sorting section of the [Ext.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) page will put you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at that part myself, only the external page referenced is zend encoded and I have not been able to receive support from the developer, which is why I am trying to find some way to filter the results in this js file.